# objective c Adding multiple projects in one workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I'm getting this issue `file not found` when `import the class from another xcode project` to the existing project when both are in single workspace.

For Ex: **A & B** are individual xcode projects.

A

|-> B

**A** is the existing xcode project file & **B** is an another xcode project file which is added to the **A**. When I import the class available in **B** to the class of **A** its showing errors like `file not found`. Here I need the class to be visible in **A**. And also I added **B** in Target dependencies of **A**. What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the A target setting page, add the file directory path you imported into Header Search Path.

[image]